# Cómo hacer que un fondo de imagen sea deslizable en CSS para móvil

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

feliz día.

Tengo el siguiente problema, hice una web con tooltips y otros elementos y en escritorio todo hermoso, perfecto, pero en móvil necesito hacer que el fondo se pueda desplazar con el dedo, está inspirada en la web de Drake, que es un render de su casa, dejo el enlace:

https://drakerelated.com/rooms/el-chico-studios

Dejo acá el prototipo en el que trabajo, por más que he intentado, no me deja trabajar el fondo de esta manera:

https://codepen.io/rzapata96/pen/mdomywx

Este sería el enlace de mi proyecto, en qué estaría fallando o qué necesito para lograr el scroll con el dedo en móvil del fondo, saludos.

Comment: El código de codepen debes agregarlo a tu pregunta

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un truco con "transform: rotate(...)"
aquí un link de como se hace
[pure-css-horizontal-scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/)

basicamente al contenedor de todo lo giras 90° en un sentido y a los hijos 90° en otro sentido

```css
/* Web Font */
* {
    font-family: 'poppins'; 
}

html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0!important;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.container > div {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Relative positioning*/
#image-map {
 
  /* Altura completa de la ventana */
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
}

/* Hide the original tooltips contents */
.pin {
    display: none;
}

/* Begin styling the tooltips and pins */
.tooltip-up, .tooltip-down {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(https://workremoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/bano.png);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.tooltip-down {
    background-position: 0 0px;
}

.tooltip {
   display:none;
    width: 170px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: 20% !important;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 100000;
  margin-top: -11px;
    margin-left: -90px;
    padding:15px;
    color: #222;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fff1d3, #ffdb90);         
}

.tooltip::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right : 10px solid transparent;
}

.tooltip-down .tooltip {
    bottom: 12px;
    top: auto;
}

.tooltip-down .tooltip::after {
  display: none;
    bottom: -10px;
    top: auto;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid #ffffff;
}

.tooltip h2 {
    font-family: poppins;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}

.tooltip ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.img-logo{
  width:20%;
  Position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
  z-index:999;}

.titulo1{position: absolute;
  width:60%;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:60px;
  top: 40%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
z-index:999;
text-align:center;}

.parrafo{position: absolute;
  width:60%;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:30px;
  top: 70%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
z-index:999;
text-align:center;}}

a {
  text-decoration: none !important; /* Elimina la barra subrayada */
  color: #000; /* Cambia el color del texto al negro (o el color deseado) */
}


         /* Estilos base del switch */
          .toggle-switch {
    z-index: 100000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130%;
    right: 20%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 35px;
}
        }

        /* Estilos del input (checkbox) oculto */
        .toggle-switch input {
            opacity: 0;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
        }

        /* Estilos del slider (la parte móvil del switch) */
        .toggle-switch .slider {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #ccc;
            -webkit-transition: .4s;
            transition: .4s;
            border-radius: 34px;
        }

        /* Estilos del estado "on" del slider */
        .toggle-switch .slider:before {
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            height: 26px;
            width: 26px;
            left: 4px;
            bottom: 4px;
            background-color: white;
            -webkit-transition: .4s;
            transition: .4s;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        /* Estilos cuando el switch está activado (checked) */
        .toggle-switch input:checked + .slider {
            background-color: #2196F3;
        }

        /* Estilos cuando el switch está activado y el slider está en la posición "on" */
        .toggle-switch input:checked + .slider:before {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
            transform: translateX(26px);
        }

.radio-inputs {z-index:100000;
  position: absolute;
  top:120%;
  left:4%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.50rem;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.radio-inputs .radio {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.radio-inputs .radio input {
  display: none;
}

.radio-inputs .radio .name {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: .7rem 2rem .7rem 2rem;
  color: #3A3A3A;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}

.radio-inputs .radio input:checked + .name {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.pin-interno{display:inline-block !important;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <label class="toggle-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="mySwitch">
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="radio-inputs">
      <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" checked="">
        <span class="name">Lorem</span>
      </label>
      <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="radio">
        <a href="https://wordpress-451873-4045671.cloudwaysapps.com/" style="text-decoration:none; color:#3A3A3A;"><span class="name">Lorem</span></a>
      </label>

      <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="radio">
        <span class="name">Lorem</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <h2 class="titulo1">¡Lorem Ipsum <br>
      <span style="font-weight:bold;line-height:0.2em;background-color:#A59B7F;">sit dolor!<span>
    </h2>

    <p class="parrafo">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <div id="image-map">
      <img width="100%" src="https://wordpress-451873-4045671.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/Group-2279.png" alt="Our Locations">
    </div>
    <a href="https://fluumbar.cl/distribuidor-autorizado-2/ !important" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000;">
      <div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="140" data-ypos="405">
        <h2>Lorem</h2>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div>
      <div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="1220" data-ypos="400">
        <h2>Lorem</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;700&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
  </style>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Tienes suficiente reputación para saber que debes evitar responder preguntas mal formuladas. La pregunta debe ser auto contenida. Las preguntas que sólo tienen un enlace al código no lo son.  Estas preguntas terminan cerradas y tu contribución se pierde.

Comment: a veces el exceso de burocracia puede ser contraproducente...

Comment: No es burocracia,  esto no es un Estado, Nación o Entidad burocrática, esto es un sitio de Q&A con normas específicas. Te invito a leer [answer]. Especialmente la sección que dice **Contesta preguntas bien formadas**. También puedes leer [ask] donde se puede leer sobre qué es una pregunta bien formulada. Hay una parte de que habla de los *fiddle*, que son aceptados como enlaces, pero que: ***también incluye el mismo código en tu pregunta***. Nuevamente, nada de eso es *burocracia*, es el formato del sitio, sus reglas, que has aceptado cuando creaste la cuenta.

Comment: Muchísima gracias por tu respuesta, te agradezco mucho tu intención de ayudarme, estimado, haré la prueba.

Comment: Y para @MauricioContreras, el código yo lo hice, y vi más cómodo poner lo que quería y lo que yo tenía hecho, noto un poco de soberbia en la respuesta, todos hemos comenzado de 0 o tenido inconvenientes, nunca está demás preguntar.

Comment: @RicardoMoisesZapataLopez lamento que pongas sentimientos a mis palabras escritas en un comentario. Yo sólo hago un aporte para ayudar al enriquecimiento del sitio, fomentando preguntas de calidad. La respueta que has recibido es muy buena, pero es probable que la misma se pierda para el resto de la comunidad porque tu pregunta pueda terminar cerrada por falta de un [mre]. Un enlace a un fiddle no es un [mre]. Piensa que el enlace puede romperse y tu pregunta no tendría sentido alguno, ya que no se podría revisar el código.

Comment: cuando el intento de poner orden se convierte en barreras para la ayuda significa que estas fallando